# R: Plot arrows perpendicular to contour lines

Tags: r, gradient, contour, arrows

I have two vectors representing x and y-coordinates in a scatter plot, and a thrid variable (z) for each (x,y)-coordinate representing the variable from which to draw contour lines. Example data are given as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(x=runif(n=30,min=-6,max=6),
               y=runif(n=30,min=-6,max=10),
               z=seq(1,100,length.out=30))
```

I use the R-package **akima** to generate the z-matrix for the contour plot

```
library(akima)
M1 <- interp(x=df$x,y=df$y,z=df$z)
contour(x=M1$x,y=M1$y,z=M1$z)
```

I now want to draw arrows perpendicular to the contourlines, preferably using something like the function "quiver" in the R-package **pracma**, with the origin of an arrow at every (x,y)-coordinate and with the arrow pointing in the direction of the gradient of the contourlines. Is there a way to do this?

My best idea so far is to somehow extract (x,y)-gradients of the contourlines and use these as velocities in the quiver function.

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Could you please clarify:  do you want the arrows to be attached to the contour lines, or at every `(M1$x, M1$y)` pair?

Comment: Good point. I want the arrows attached at every (M1$x,M1$y) pair

Comment: You can use the raster package "terrain" function with the "aspect" option to get the angle from a point on an elevation raster. e.g. `plot(terrain(raster(M1),"aspect"))` - then sample the raster at the points, draw arrows with sines and cosines...

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pracma` package has a `gradient` function that can do this for you using the original `M1$z` values.  For example, using your code to get `M1` after `set.seed(123)`:

```
contour(x=M1$x,y=M1$y,z=M1$z, asp = 1) # asp = 1 needed so things look perpendicular

library(pracma)
g <- gradient(M1$z, M1$x, M1$y)

x <- outer(M1$x, M1$y, function(x, y) x)
y <- outer(M1$x, M1$y, function(x, y) y)

quiver(x, y, g$Y, g$X, scale = 0.02, col = "blue")
```

Note that the gradient labels in the `quiver` plot have been swapped.  Maybe I set up the `x` and `y` values transposed from the way the package expects.  Here's what you get:

[image]

Comment: Follow-up question: Do you know of a way to attach the arrows to the original (x,y)-coordinates? (df$x,df$y)

Comment: You might be able to use `pracma::interp2` to interpolate gradient values to those points, but in a quick try just now, I found it fails on any points on the convex hull of your dataset.  With 30 points, that's half of the points.

Comment: OK will try to use interp2, grateful for your efforts